# Datatable doesn't showing the row's child

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatable

Jquery code to load the subrow :

```js
function format ( d ) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    var div = $('<div/>')
        .addClass( 'loading' )
        .text( 'Loading...' );
 
 var product_id = d['DT_RowId'];//This is the ItemId
 var btn_action = 'item_detail'; 
 
    $.ajax( {
        url: 'item_action.php', //Calling the function
        data: {
            product_id:product_id, 
   btn_action:btn_action //Set item_id and variable se
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function ( test ) {
            div
                .html( data.html )
                .removeClass( 'loading' );
        }
    } );
 
    return div;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML Code -->

<table id="item_data" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th></th>
   <th>Item Code</th>
   <th>Item Description</th>
   <th>Product Line</th>         
   <th>Purchase Standard Cost</th>
   <th>Last Receipt</th>         
   <th>Status</th>         
   <th></th>
   <th></th>
   <th></th>
  </tr>
</thead>                 
</table>

<!-- PHP Code -->
<?php

$data = array();
  $data[]='<table class="table table-bordered table-striped dataTable no-footer" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;"';  
  foreach($result as $row)//Fill the table cells
  {   
   $output .= '
   <tr>
    <td>Price Code</td>
    <td>'.$row["pricecode_code"].'</td>
   </tr>   
   ';
   $subarray[]=$output;
   $data[] = $sub_array;
  } 
  $data[]='</table>';
  $output = array(
  "draw"       =>  intval($_POST["draw"]),   
  "html"       =>  $data
  );  
  echo json_encode($output); //Return the table formatted   
?>
```

When I click on the details it add Loading Class but doesn't show the details! Where is the error?

Comment: What exactly is not working?  Do you get any errors?  How does it look now?  What do you mean by regular `<TR>` and `<TD>`

Comment: If you are expecting the `return` in your `success` callback to send that value back as the result of the `format()` function, that's not how ajax works.  The first "a" in "ajax" stands for "asynchronous".  Your `format()` function is going to complete and return _before_ your ajax callback executes.

Comment: So what if I replace return with this: $('#product_details').html(data);

Comment: then you have a good chance to get what you expect! (if there's an element with id 'product_details')

Comment: If you want the value of `data` to be the entire content of your `#product_details` element, then yes.  It's a little hard to say without seeing your starting HTML and what you want the result HTML to be.

Comment: I'll show you the html code

Comment: `<table id="item_data" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
       <thead>
        <tr>
         <th></th>
         <th>Item Code</th>
         <th>Item Description</th>
         <th>Product Line</th>         
         <th>Purchase Standard Cost</th>
         <th>Last Receipt</th>         
         <th>Status</th>         
         <th></th>
         <th></th>
         <th></th>
        </tr>
       </thead>                 
      </table>`

Comment: Please put code in your question, not in comments.

Comment: Okay, so with what you have now, everything between your `<table id="item_data" ...` and `</table>` will be replaced by the response from your ajax call is.  That's probably not what you want.  First, you probably don't want to get rid of your table headers, and second, you have a second set of `<table>` tags being sent back in your response.  Try removing those tags from your response and look into replacing `$('#item_data').html(data)` with something else.  Check out [.after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/) and [.append](http://api.jquery.com/after/) for some options.

Comment: I'm trying to create the items_detail it means that anytime I click on the row it will open up subrow with the item's details. I can do it with "return" but I can't do with ajax. how can I risolve it?

Comment: of course! .after and .append... I'll try it and I'll let you know if this solution is working

Comment: I put after in the code and It's working right now but the problem is that I'm not understanding when I click on detail it open the detail but doesn't put selected in the class and when I click again it doesn't remove class and it put the table details again

Comment: I updated the Function "Format" and I don't understand why it add the Loading Class but it doesn't show me the details.